# What is the definition of a frontend model and backend model

Tags: model

I see methods like getBackend* and getFrontend, could some one be able to define what the a backend/ frontend model is and its responsibilities?

Just really to give a definition in my head of what it is. I presume a back end model is related to the admin interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the backend model to perform different actions when saving an attribute value:
Validate the value or perform an action before the value is saved or loaded.
For example all data attributes should have the backend model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Datetime` (`eav/entity_attrbute_backend_datetime`) or something that inherits it.
This way you ensure the value inserted in the database is formated to look like `Y-m-d H:i:s` independent from the locale and date format used. Take a look at what backend models can do by inspecting the classes in  `app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend` folder.

The frontend model is somehow the other way arround. It takes the value from the database and performs different actions to display it in the right way (in admin or frontend). maybe you get an idea of the actions performed from the classes in `app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend`