# installing a new table for my module

Tags: database, install-script

I am writing an uncomplicated install script

```
$table->addColumn(
    'name',
    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
    255,
    array(
        'nullable' => false,
    )
);
```

i need this column to only have unique values (it is not the tables primary key), also is there a way to only allow lowercase and no special characters (only a-z)

Comment: Is this a core table? Is this a custom table? If so could we see the schema of the table (`SHOW CREATE [table]`) ? Could you show us the entire installer script?

Comment: a custom table  `$this->startSetup();
 $table = new Varien_Db_Ddl_Table();
 $table->setName($this->getTable('namespace_affiliates/affiliates'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing all of the information I would suggest there are a few ways you can approach this.

### Unique strings

This can be enforced by MySQL by adding a `UNIQUE` key constraint.

In SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD UNIQUE (email)
```

or expressed as Varien DDL:

```
$table->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName('youmodule/modelalias', array('email'), Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE),
    array('email'), array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE)
```

### Alpha entry only

- To enforce the schema you could create a **Backend Model** (read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6423/336) to validate the input
- You could also use a backend model to strip non-alpha characters out instead of validating
- You could use a MySQL `TRIGGER` to enforce the schema as well on INSERT or UPDATE

However, to my knowledge, there is no built-in column type in MySQL that will enforce this schema for you.

Comment: thank you what is the varibal `$installer`?

Comment: also what is `youmodule/modelalias` i assume youmodule is my module's name bu what is modelalias ?

Comment: also is there any documentation on creating and applying a Backend Model?